# What is the correct way to install Celery/Redis to run the tasks on another server?

Tags: redis, celery

The web server itself runs django. I would like the web server to delegate the actual tasks work to another server.

Answer (score 1):

First, setup your redis server on the remote server. Change your django configuration to connect to this server.

When you deploy your app, I recommend using [fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric) to deploy to your web server and your worker server. It should handle the restart logic as well.